# windows 8.1 keydown does not work on FullScreen MediaElement

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro, keydown, mediaelement

I want to disable full screen with ESC when it is in full screen. It does not take the event handler anywhere. I also put KeyDown handler to main grid

```
 <ContentControl KeyDown="ContentControl_KeyDown">
     <MediaElement x:Name="Video_frame"  KeyDown="ContentControl_KeyDown" MediaEnded="Video_frame_MediaEnded" AutoPlay="True" MediaFailed="Video_frame_MediaFailed" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" RealTimePlayback="True">
     </MediaElement>
 </ContentControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling the Xaml KeyDown event, which is local to the UIElement and then routed, handle the [CoreWindow.KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.core.corewindow.keydown.aspx) event which covers the app's entire window and is generally better for app-global hotkeys.